# Integrate ZOHO API with Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, api, zoho

I tried to integrate Laravel application with ZOHO SDK but it's not working, `zohocrm/php-sdk` is for PHP not for Laravel. I have tried third parties packages but none is working.

- Zoho API Version: 2.0
- Laravel Version: 5.7

I have tried these packages also

https://packagist.org/packages/atlasresults/zoho-laravel-crm-php
https://github.com/rahulreghunath/Zoho

The issue with Official SDK is it could not find the class `ZCRMRestClient` when generating grant-token.
https://www.zoho.com/crm/help/developer/server-side-sdks/php.html

```
public function abc()
{
    ZCRMRestClient::initialize();
    $oAuthClient = ZohoOAuth::getClientInstance();
    $grantToken = “paste_the_self_authorized_grant_token_here”;
    $oAuthTokens = $oAuthClient->generateAccessToken($grantToken);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you do `composer require ryosensei/zoho-laravel-crm-php in your project diratory

Comment: Yes I have installed this package also, but it is giving some error at time of installation.

Comment: what error was can you show me

Comment: `composer require ryosensei/zoho-laravel-crm-php` and 

Error Message: 
Could not find a matching version of package ryosensei/zoho-laravel-crm-php. Check the package spelling, your  
   version constraint and that the package is available in a stability which matches your minimum-stability (de  
  v).

Comment: have you installed `composer require zohocrm/php-sdk`

Comment: Yes I did install, and after that I have this error. Is it working fine at your end ?

Comment: not yet tried bro

Comment: FWIW, we tried to use their SDK as well and it never worked! So now we just use their REST APIs

Answer (score 0):

When using Zoho CRM SDK with Laravel, all the class all registered in the global namespace. Just add a "\" before the class name as follows:

```
public function abc()
{
    \ZCRMRestClient::initialize();
    $oAuthClient = \ZohoOAuth::getClientInstance();
    $grantToken = “paste_the_self_authorized_grant_token_here”;
    $oAuthTokens = $oAuthClient->generateAccessToken($grantToken);
}
```